# Making categories of \ref to colour them differently?

Tags: hyperref, ref

It is possible to define particular category of \ref{} and then set colour for that particular category across the entire document?
Currently, all my citations are blue, which is fine. I have cross referenced some tables, figures and chapter sections. Can these be defined separately and coloured?

I have some examples where I do `{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}\ref{Table16}}` for an individual or so, but that would be cumbersome across an entire document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the `cleveref` package, by setting the link color in the label name for specific types of references. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}figure}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}figures}
\Crefname{figure}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}Figure}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}Figures}
\crefname{table}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}table}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}tables}
\Crefname{table}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}Table}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}Tables}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\label{sec}

\begin{figure}
\centering\fbox{A figure}
\caption{with caption}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering\fbox{A table}
\caption{with caption}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

See \cref{fig} and \cref{tab} in \cref{sec}.
\end{document}
```

Note that each color is set four times: in the names for singular and plural references, each in lower case (used with `\cref`) and upper case (used with `\Cref`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!